# Android RemoteView set StateListDrawable programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-widget, android-drawable, remoteview

I have a Widget for my Android App. On this Widget there is a button. The user can freely choose the color of the button. So I also have to set the colors for the different button states dynamically.

**Normally, I would do something like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorButtonRedTransparentPressed"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorButtonRedTransparentPressed"
        android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorButtonRedTransparentNotPressed" />
</selector>
```

**As mentioned, I have to do this dynamically because the user is free to choose the color:**

```
  StateListDrawable drawable = new StateListDrawable();
  drawable.addState(new int[] {}, new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(customButton.getColorHex())));
  drawable.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed }, new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0000")));
```

**The challenge:**

The button is on a Widget. So i cannot just simply call:

```
myButton.setBackground(drawable);
```

I need to call something like this:

```
remoteView.setInt(R.id.button_fixedvalue, "setBackground", drawable)
```

But the function expects an integer and I don't have one.

Does anyone have a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1

If there is a limited number of colors that the user can choose from, you could create a selector resource for each color option and then use the `setInt()` method to assign the resource ID that corresponds to the selected color.

## Option 2

If by "freely choose" you mean that the user can select any possible color - or at least from a very large number - option 1 won't work of course.
Depending on what your drawable exactly looks like, you could try this instead:

1. Create only a single selector resource.
2. Use an `ImageView` for your button.
3. Apply the color as a tint to the `ImageView` using the `ImageView.setColorFilter()` method.
   That would look something like this:

```
remoteView.setInt(R.id.button_id, "setColorFilter", Color.parseColor("#0000"))
```